# What is the right way to redirect in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to make an MVC php framework. I am trying to write testable code. I know `exit` or `die()` is not a good solution after `header("Location: http://example.com");`.

That's how I am currently doing redirect:
Here is simpler version of my code.

```
<?php
// create a RedirectException class
class RedirectException extends \Exception {}
```

---

```
<?php
// it is index.php
try {
    include 'view.php'
}  catch (RedirectException $e) {
    header(sprintf("Location: %s", $e->getMessage());
    header('HTTP/1.1 302 Found', true, 302);
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    // print exception here or, do something else
}
```

---

```
<?php
// it is view.php
$url = 'http://example.com';
throw new RedirectException($url);
```

---

#### This flow should works fine when I run `index.php`

It looks to me like, I am doing it right way. 
The problem is not with response code.

#### The question is, I need to know: Managing redirect with `Exception` is a good idea? or I should try it in some other way?

Comment: Managing non exceptional situations with Exceptions feels wrong imo. I would suggest that your handling should just naturally reach the end of code execution at the point of redirect (or normal response) instead of abruptly terminating. This will also give you the option of performing post-processing tasks after you have send the full response if you need to .

Comment: I think most MVC frameworks define some function `RedictTo..`, and in your controllers you can then `return RedirectTo("other_url/action");` - and the framework will then invoke the other action, as if it had been invoked by a user. Part of that might be setting the headers as you do now.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned, a redirect as an action taken when an exception is throw is not really accurate from a semantic viewpoint. Typically, a redirect is implemented in the layer that deals with providing a response to the client, because the redirect is from a technical perspective actually implemented here as a header (`Location`).

A very rough example of how this would more cleanly work is when a controller in your MVC architecture is able to provide a "response", that as part of its state could signal a redirect, e.g.

```
class SomeController {
  public function home(Request $request, Response $response) {
    return $response->redirect('/somewhere');
  }
}
```

Which in its implementation would simply attach a `Location: /somewhere` header to the response that your web application provides to the client.

Comment: When I call `$response = SomeController::home()`, I get a `Response` object. But How I will know I need to redirect?

Comment: Your response object should be able to provide its headers, which would include the Location header and via that the redirect behaviour.

Comment: It can be like this?

class Response {
    private $content;
    private $status_code; 
    private $redirect_url;

    public function send() {
        if($this->status_code == 302) {
            header("Location: http://example.com");
        } else {
           echo $this->content;
        }
    }
 }

Comment: I would just have $headers as an array and when your application sends the response it traverses the headers and sets them before outputting the response body, which should also be attached to the response.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But I need to get the `URL` what is sent from controller. Can I add a `private $redirect_url` in `Response class` so that I can redirect to that `URL`?

Comment: The URL would just be contained in the array like `$headers = [“Location” => “someurl”]`.

Comment: I found the solution. I will post it soon. Thank you all.

Comment: Make your answer fit OP's question.